# Create target="_blank" link using Kohana MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I have a link which works, using a template in kohana MVC. But how do I adapt it, so it opens in a new page, would be target="_blank" in html, but Kohoana documentation isn't clear. Thanks

```
  <?php echo HTML::anchor($gift->url, HTML::chars($gift->name')) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the anchor tag in Kohana is like

> anchor( string $uri [, string $title = NULL , array
>   $attributes = NULL , mixed $protocol = NULL , boolean $index = bool
>   TRUE ] )

So, in third parameter **attributes** you can pass the other attributes that you want to pass for anchor tag. Something like below:

```
<?php echo HTML::anchor($gift->url, HTML::chars($gift->name), array('target' => '_blank', 'name' => 'anchor1')) ?>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks but I tried that and some variations and get ERROREXCEPTION [ PARSE ERROR ]: SYNTAX ERROR, UNEXPECTED '['

Comment: It should work.... please see this https://github.com/kohana/kohana2/blob/master/system/helpers/html.php
here you see variable $windowed_urls is used to enable and disable target link...please check ur file

Comment: yes actually <?php echo HTML::anchor($gift->url, HTML::chars($gift->name), array('target' => '_blank', 'name' => 'anchor1')) ?> when I looked at comments in code of that link

Comment: @GAV Great! if it helped you! but am surprised array() or [] both are same.... why working with array() and not with []

Comment: `[]` is short for `array()`, and this was added in php5.3 or later. (I don't remember)